# Redirecting to log in screen if not authenticated - ASP.NET Core 2.2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm trying to redirect users who are not authenticated/logged in regardless of where the navigation points to. I'm just using the basic ASP.NET template in Visual Studio 2017.

I'm using Core 2.2 and whenever I seem to find a solution, it's out of date.

Thanks!

Comment: have u tried the doc's for 2.2 it has an example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: @saj Are URL rewrites necessary though? Seems like such a basic thing, I thought it would have been easier. New ASP.NET dev here mind you, I may have missed the trick entirely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
   {
      // Cookie settings
      options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
      options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);

      options.LoginPath = "/Identity/Account/Login"; // Set here your login path.
      options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Identity/Account/AccessDenied"; // set here your access denied path.
      options.SlidingExpiration = true;
   });

   services.AddMvc(options =>
   {
        options.Filters.Add( new AuthorizeFilter());
   }).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
}
```

Comment: Are there any dependencies for AuthorizeFilter? It's coming back as not found.

Comment: use `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization`

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what other have said, try adding [Authorize] to your main controller.

```
namespace Project.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
```

Comment: Thanks! That answered another question I had.